# JQuery FadeIn not working with JS button click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this simple code that generates a random number from 0-3 and upon clicking the button the generated number appears in the div. I tried making it fade in using JQuery but it's not working. jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/Montinyek/3cj7nbop/27/

```
function random() {
let number = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
let result = ""

switch(number) {
case 0: 
result = "Zero";
break;
case 1:
result = "One";
break;
case 2:
result = "Two";
break;
case 3:
result = "Three";
}

return result; 
}


function final() {
document.addEventListener("click", function(){
  document.getElementById("div").innerHTML = random();
});
}

$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $("#div").fadeIn('slow');
    
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code doesn't work for 2 reasons.

1. You didn't include jQuery.js in the page
2. The `#div` wasn't hidden to start with.

Also note that you should avoid the `onclick` and other event related attributes as they are not good practice. As you're using jQuery anyway, the logic which updates the HTML of the `div` can be moved in to there. Try this:

```js
function random() {
  let number = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
  let result = ""

  switch (number) {
    case 0:
      result = "Zero";
      break;
    case 1:
      result = "One";
      break;
    case 2:
      result = "Two";
      break;
    case 3:
      result = "Three";
  }

  return result;
}


$(document).ready(function() {
  $("button").click(function() {
    $("#div").html(random()).fadeIn('slow');
  });
});
```

```css
#div {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Click me</button>

<div id="div"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you. What are my other options if I'm to avoid using onclick? It's just that it was taught on W3 schools so I thought it was the right way to do it.

Comment: Never use W3Schools. Their articles are often outdated and sometimes just plain wrong. If you're looking for a good JS/HTML/CSS resource, use [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/) - check the references link in the top left. Best practice is to use unobtrusive event handlers. In jQuery, the example is above using [`click()`](https://api.jquery.com/click) or [`on()`](https://api.jquery.com/on). In native JS it would be to use [`addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)

Comment: Just one more question, how would I make <button> receive the function with an addEventListener() without using onclick in native JS? Sorry if this is a noob question, I'm just starting to dive into JS.